# Jmeter - Passing parameter one by one from a variable

Tags: jmeter

I am a JMeter new user.
I have the following scenario - To search for a Name in search text box. Parameterized the Name in CSV. But while searching instead of entire name being passed as parameter i.e. ${Name}, I need to pass each character of ${Name} to individual HTTP Request, say for request 1, parameter is N, Request 2 - Parameter a and so on and the search result is displayed for the last request when N, a, m, e have all been passed.
How do i handle this using Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send multiple request then in the csv, give the input field as required.

Example:-

1st Cell:-N

2nd Cell:-Na

etc

But, check if there is a request being send for every word you type in the field to the server using fiddler or any other sniffing tool. If yes, then use the above approach. Also, you can try using jmeter recording for the scenerio.

If, not then you need to have one request which is sending the full variable i.e. Name.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Test Plan
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.get('Name').eachWithIndex {letter, idx ->
       vars.put('letter_' + idx, letter)
   }
   ```

   where `vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it is being used to read `${Name}` variable and generate variables like `${letter_1}`, `${letter_2}`, etc. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details.
3. Add [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) after the JSR223 Sampler and configure it as follows:

   [image: JMeter Foreach Controller]
4. Put HTTP Request sampler as a child of the ForEach Controller and use `${currentLetter}` variable reference where required

   [image: JMeter Iterate Each Letter in variable]